# Change Button text in html and angular 2

Tags: html, angular, button, disable

I want to change the button text once it is selected, logically it is working fine, initially YES button is highlighting once i click on it sightly change then if i hover disable symbol will show 
first image : before click
second image : after click
So what i want is , when i click on yes it should change it to NO and if i hover disable symbol has to show
here is my HTML code

```
 <div>
                    <button type="button" class="confirm"
                            [disabled]="(isConfirmed && agree) || (isConfirmed && nutral)"
                            style="color: blue;"
                            (click)="sayYes()">
                        YES
                    </button>

</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to change the text. I would make an interpolation with your 'disabled' property conditions, like this:

```
<button type="button" class="confirm"
    [disabled]="(isConfirmed && agree) || (isConfirmed && nutral)"
    style="color: blue;"
    (click)="sayYes()">
        {{ (isConfirmed && agree) || (isConfirmed && nutral) ? 'NO' : 'YES' }}
</button>
```

And to disable button on hover, you can add css property 'pointer-events' with value 'none'. This will make your button unclickable, and then you style it on your own.

```
button:hover{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the shortest way would be to conditionally render text inside of a button with `innerText`

```
<button [innerText]="condition ? 'YES' : 'NO'"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`in yourComponent.html`**

```
<div>
                    <button type="button" class="confirm"
                            [disabled]="(isConfirmed && agree) || (isConfirmed && nutral)"
                            style="color: blue;"
                            (click)="sayYes()">
                       {{buttonTitle}}
                    </button>

</div>
```

In **.ts**

Create a new boolean variabile isClickedOnYes and inizialize it to false.

```
isClickedOnYes: boolean = false;
titleButton: string = 'YES'
```

When you click on button it became true and title became NO, when you click another time,
it became false and title became YES;

In **sayYes()**  function  you can implement a logic like this:

```
sayYes() {
  if(this.isClickedOnYes == false){
    this.titleButton= 'NO'
    this.isClickedOnYes = true;
  }
  else {
    this.titleButton= 'YES'
    this.isClickedOnYes = false;
 }

 }
```